# MySql drop foreign key in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

How to drop foreign key in innodb table?
        ALTER TABLE locations1 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_locations1(id); is this correct?

Comment: Nope, that key has a name, just use that name (`DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_locations1;` most likely, if not, check your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for how the index is called).

Comment: You will find a solution for your problem in this SO response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14122155/3388491

Comment: Beside reading the manual (a good answer for this question is RTFM) I have PHPMYADMIN where I do such stuff and it shows me the command it used. Saves the time to look it up in the manual.