# Rails migrations—temporarily ignore foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm trying to change a table's `id` field to be a `uuid`

Here's my code:

```
class AddUuidToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    add_column :projects, :uuid, :string, limit:36, null: false, first: true
    add_column :projects, :old_id, :integer

    Project.all.each do |p|
      p.update!(old_id: p.id)
    end
    change_table :projects do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE projects ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"

    Project.all.each do |p|
      # has_one image
      Image.find(p.old_id).update!(project: p) 
      # has_many stories
      Story.where(project_id: p.old_id).each do |s|
        s.update!(project: p)
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

This migration breaks when trying `t.remove :id`, because of a foreign key constraint. The error message is:

```
Mysql2::Error: Cannot drop column 'id': needed in a foreign key constraint 'fk_rails_be41fd4bb7' of table 'db_dev.stories': ALTER TABLE `projects` DROP `id`
```

The thing is, if the whole migration ran then I would be swapping the `id` column out with another one, and fixing up the foreign keys too. So, is there any way to ignore the constraints for the migration?

Comment: try dropping the constraint first then adding it again later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122031/how-to-remove-constraints-from-my-mysql-table

Comment: you can also just set uuid as the primary key and just let active record know that. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key

Comment: I would consider creating separate data migration covered with tests. More on this https://robots.thoughtbot.com/data-migrations-in-rails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Project.connection.disable_referential_integrity do
  Project.delete_all # An example
end
```

[`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_referential_integrity`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L369).

Rails 4.2+.

Comment: Also note to make your schema changes inside a block passed to this function, so `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_referential_integrity do ... end`, so that any FK enforcement change is rolled back even if your migration fails.

Answer (score 3):

On mysql, you can do this :

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'
  # Your statements
  ...
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My final code

The `if` and `unless` statements were there because I was writing and testing incrementally (and a failed migration still had lasting effects). The main thing is deleting the foreign keys then adding them back in the end (deleting the keys doesn't delete the `id` fields in the db, only the constraints.

```
class AddUuidToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    # remove constraint
    if foreign_key_exists?(:stories, :projects)
      say("removing foreign key constraints")

      remove_foreign_key "stories", "projects"
      remove_foreign_key "images", "projects"
    end

    # create UUID id column
    unless column_exists?(:projects, :id, :string)
      say("adding UUID column")

      add_column :projects, :uuid, :string, limit:36, null: false, first: true
      add_column :projects, :old_id, :integer

      Project.all.each do |p|
        p.update!(old_id: p.id, uuid: SecureRandom.uuid)
      end

      change_table :projects do |t|
        t.remove :id
        t.rename :uuid, :id
      end
      execute "ALTER TABLE projects ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
    end

    # update foreign keys
    if(Image.first.project_id.is_a? Integer)
      say("updating foreign keys")

      # change foreign key fields to STRING(36)
      change_column :images, :project_id, :string, limit:36, null: false
      change_column :stories, :project_id, :string, limit:36, null: false

      Project.all.each do |p|
        # has_one soi
        Image.find_by(project: p.old_id).update!(project: p)

        # has_many stories
        Snippet.where(project_id: p.old_id).each do |s|
          s.update!(project: p)
        end
      end
    end

    # add constraints back
    unless foreign_key_exists?(:stories, :projects)
      say("adding foreign key constraints back")

      add_foreign_key "stories", "projects"
      add_foreign_key "images", "projects"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have mixed mysql - sqlite environment, you could do:

```
class AddUuidToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'Mysql2'
    # Your code
    # ...
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;' if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'Mysql2'
  end

  def down
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'Mysql2'
    # Your code
    # ...
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;' if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'Mysql2'
  end
end
```