# Unable to drop a foreign key column in MySql

Tags: mysql

I added a column in a table (query below)

```
ALTER TABLE `acct_doc_item_data`
ADD fk_job_id INT(11), 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_job_id) REFERENCES `job`(`job_id`);
```

Now I want to drop this column (fk_job_id). I tried these queries but they are giving error.

```
ALTER TABLE `acct_doc_item_data` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_job_id`;
ALTER TABLE `acct_doc_item_data` DROP COLUMN `fk_job_id`;
```

1st Alter statement gives error as - `Can't DROP 'fk_job_id'; check that column/key exists` (But the column exists).

2nd Alter statement gives error as - `Cannot drop index 'fk_job_id': needed in a foreign key constraint`

Comment: you need to drop the name of the index, 
`ALTER TABLE acct_doc_item_data DROP FOREIGN KEY <foreign key index/constraint>;`, you cannot use the column name when dropping foreign key, only when dropping the column.

Comment: You did not provide a foreign key name when you added the foreign key , if memory serves mysql will allocate one for you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column/18825955 to identify the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first drop the foreign key constraint then drop the column

eg:

```
alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name


alter table table_name drop column column_name
```

to get constraint name use this

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='YourTableName';
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case(phpmyadmin and Mysql InnoDB) You cannot just do:

```
alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name
```

becouse it gives "Acces denied" for root "to database 'information_schema' "

But I could go to Structure tab -> Relation view and from there you can drop desired fk

Related topic: [How to remove constraints from my MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122031/how-to-remove-constraints-from-my-mysql-table)