# DROP CONSTRAINT is not able to find constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I try to drop a constraint:

```
USE `mydb`;

BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `mydb` DROP CONSTRAINT `myconstraint`;
COMMIT;
```

And it replies with:

```
ERROR 1091 (42000) at line 6: Can't DROP CONSTRAINT `myconstraint`; check that it exists
```

But the constraint exists:

```
MariaDB [(mydb)]> select * from information_schema.table_constraints WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME                                               | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME      | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| def                | mydb              | PRIMARY                                                       | mydb         | mytable         | PRIMARY KEY     |
| def                | mydb              | name                                                          | mydb         | mytable         | UNIQUE          |
| def                | mydb              | myconstraint                                                  | mydb         | mytable         | FOREIGN KEY     |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove constraints from my MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122031/how-to-remove-constraints-from-my-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that MariaDB (MySql?) does not allow to remove foreign key constraints with the syntax `DROP CONSTRAINT`. It must be dropped like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` DROP FOREIGN KEY `myconstraint`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing "schema" (aka "database") and "table"):  `ALTER TABLE mytable ...`

Comment: My constraint is on a a table. I can find the constraint, but I can not drop it.

Comment: Try `USE mydb; ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT myconstraint;`

Comment: Which is what I have in my question and is not working. See my answer for the solution

Answer (score 0):

This issue is documented in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17599. It was fixed in version 10.2.22 and 10.3.13 (11-02-2019).
I sugest update MariaDB version or, like @volingas wrote, the sintax:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` DROP FOREIGN KEY `myconstraint`;
```