# Syntax error in MySQL 5.7 for use CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to fix some error in Jira as mention in [this page](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Error-after-Upgrade-Jira-7-13-gt-8-9-1/qaq-p/1420426) but when I try to run an SQL query, I got the below error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT
> `fk_ao_8542f1_ifj_obj_attr_val_object_attribute_id`' at line 1

My Query is:

```
ALTER TABLE AO_8542F1_IFJ_OBJ_ATTR_VAL 
DROP CONSTRAINT `fk_ao_8542f1_ifj_obj_attr_val_object_attribute_id`
```

How I can fix this Query? I use MySQL version 5.7

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for your table.

Comment: I want to use the "Insight" plugin in Jira and those tables create by plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove constraints from my MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122031/how-to-remove-constraints-from-my-mysql-table)

Comment: No @GSerg, unfortunately not working for me!

Answer (score 2):

Drop MySQL foreign key constraints
To drop a foreign key constraint, you use the ALTER TABLE statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the name of the constraint, I believe it's a foreign key and MySQL has a different approach to drop foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE AO_8542F1_IFJ_OBJ_ATTR_VAL
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_ao_8542f1_ifj_obj_attr_val_object_attribute_id`
```