# How to delete composite primary key

Tags: mysql

I am having table friends_list i want to drop its composite primary key(`friend_of_id`,`friends_id_is`) and want to create a new composite primary key(`friend_of_aid`,`friends_aid`).

for removing primary key i wrote the query

```
ALTER TABLE friends_list  DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

but this is showing following error

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\xrcwrn_sms\#sql-14d4_e0' to '.\xrcwrn_sms\friends_list' (errno: 150)
```

I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111291/remove-primary-key-in-mysql) but for composite primary key this is not working
My table structure pic is as follow

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check foreign keys on this table, for example using next query -

```
SELECT
  *
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
  WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'db name' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'your table';
```

You need to recreate all these foreign keys:

1. Drop foreign key(s)
2. Recreate rpimary key
3. Create foreign key(s)

Comment: I tried query showing error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = `friends_list` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4`

Comment: Add AND keyword between conditions.