# Sql Upload file error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to upload sql file by BigDump

sql file size is 766MB (784616 KB)

I have try more then 10 time also increase mx size etc. But got same error.

```
Error at the line 2134851: (1815, 95, 1);

Query: --
--
INSERT INTO `access` (`userid`, `forumid`, `accessmask`) VALUES
(1815, 95, 1)

MySQL: Duplicate entry '1815-95' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

File size is too large so i can't open this in any editor , So any help regarding this? So i can skip this line .

Also if bigdump stop one this line and next time can i start from this link or i must need to delete all tables and it will start from "0".

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to edit a 750M file in an editor, it will just take a while :-) I've edited files in excess of 2GB in Vim, for example... In any case, you could also use `sed(1)`, or somesuch...

Comment: Well, *Duplicate entry '1815-95' for key 'PRIMARY'* is a rather straightforward message and doesn't mention anything about file size. You've designed your table so it cannot hold duplicates in columns `userid`, `forumid` and now you're trying to violate such restriction.

Comment: You could always import into a table without the constraint then modify the record after and re-apply the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the primary key in the table. (See [Remove Primary Key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2111291/4350148)).  Then find duplicates in  the table using  group  by and count and remove them. Then add the primary key constraint back in.